# How to properly show/hide the right border of Table's TD

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I want to flexibly hide/show the right border of some TDs inside a table, but the border color of the TDs could be different, e.g. red, black, or blue, so I cannot just do something like below:

```
td.style.borderRightColor = shouldShow ? 'black' : 'white';
```

since the td border could be in any color and with any background, e.g.

```
 <td style="border:1px solid rgb(xx, yy, zz);width:100px"></td>
```

Instead, I am wondering if there is a way to make the TDs' border transparent. Like, setting the A of RGBA of the border to be 0, but in order to do that I first need to know the current RGB of the border? Or, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You will need to provide a bit more code for context, how are you defining the borders you want to be able to show/hide?

Comment: I added a bit more info, bascailly the border width/color and the background is unknown. So I think the code should just make it transparent without altering the original color/background color

Comment: Just set `border-right {none}`, color will be irrelevant

Comment: @charlietfl and then when `shouldShow` is true where does he old configuration come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`border-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width). Or in your case, `border-right-width`:

```
const borderWidth = '1px'; // this will depend on what width you're using already.
const noBorderWidth = '0';
td.style.borderRightWidth = shouldShow ? borderWidth : noBorderWidth ;
```

or [`border-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) (`border-right-style`):

```
const borderStyle = 'solid'; // this will depend on what border-style you're using already.
const noBorderStyle = 'none';
td.style.borderRightStyle = shouldShow ? borderStyle : noBorderStyle;
```

Comment: Thanks Callum. I tried your approach here: https://jsfiddle.net/flyingbee2012/udpeq0w9/101/ but it seems the border is still visible, not sure if I am doing it in the correct way.

Comment: I am thinking of using something like: style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("Example"), null)  then get the rgb from stylegetPropertyValue('border-right-color'), then apply a 4th value (opacity) to it.

Comment: @flyingbee Ah right, your problem is that adjoining cells both have borders, so hiding the right border for one cell doesn't affect the left border of the next cell, so you're still seeing that one. [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/5648otdL/)

Comment: Got it, it seems it is the "border-collapse:collapse;" that is causing this issue, if I remove this setting, either col.style.borderRightStyle = 'none'; or col.style.borderRightWidth = '0'; would work. Thanks!